# Parent or child composable trigger click simultaneously

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, android-jetpack-compose

I have a parent composable

```
Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .width(tableWidth)
        .fillMaxHeight(),
) {
    cells.forEachIndexed { it1, cell ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(tableHeight),
        ) {
            for (i in cell.indices) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(sideBarWidth)
                        .height(headerHeight)
                        .clickable {
                          //event here
                        }
                ) {
                    eventContent(
                        studentScore =  cell,
                        listIndex = it1,
                        index = i,
                        onEvent = onEvent // event here
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a child which is the eventContent composable as showed above.

I want the parent or child composable to trigger both click events. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to perform the same thing coming from 2 click actions?, one coming from a child and one from a parent?, is the parent's onClick not enough?

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. on parent click i want to sent the list to an event and on child click the index and the object. How can i do this in different way?

Comment: Why not simply create a lambda callback and just pass everything you need to it when you perform a single onClick?, please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a `lambda` callback where you can set all the things you need as its parameters.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(onEventCallback: (List, Int, Cell) -> Unit) {

    ...
    ...
    ...

      Box {
          eventContent(
              studentScore =  cell,
              listIndex = it1,
              index = i,
              onEvent = { selectedCell ->
                   onEventCallback(cells, i, selectedCell) // just pass everything on a single call
              }
          )
      }

    ...
    ...
}
```

And you can simply do separate things from the call site

```
 MyComposable { list, index, cell ->
       doSomethingOnTheList(list)
       doSomethingOnIndexAndCell(index, cell)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this and accept as right answer but i  want to ask if the are performance issues when pass list to child composable, and maybe faster to have each composable only the object

Comment: I'm not sure what performance issues your'e referring to, but simply passing a list to a function should not be something you need to worry about performance hit.